# Variable value changes depending on domain using Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, how can we have

```
$pathToFile = '/var/www/awesome'
$mysqlServer = '111.111.111.0'
```

when domain of the site is `www.mysite.com`, and

```
$pathToFile = '/var/www/hackish'
$mysqlServer = '111.111.111.1'
```

when domain of the site is `dev.mysite.com`?

Answer (score 2):

Create a different environment for each domain, under `bootstrap/start.php`, and add specific file for it, under `app/start` folder. In your example, you could have:

**bootstrap/start.php**

```
// ...
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'production'  => array('www.mysite.com'),
    'development' => array('dev.mysite.com'),
));
```

**app/start/production.php**

```
$pathToFile = '/var/www/awesome';
$mysqlServer= '111.111.111.0';
```

**app/start/development.php**

```
$pathToFile = '/var/www/hackish';
$mysqlServer= '111.111.111.1';
```

You should not though, that if you're working with the default configuration files, the same is valid for them. You can read more on the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration).